# Load img from local Drive

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, jquery-events

I have the following HTML Tags:

```
<input id="bigPicture" name="bigPicture" type="file" value="">
<img src="test.png" id="test1">
```

User select file and I want to preview this file inside image size as `onchange` event:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("#bigPicture").change(function() {
    alert($("#bigPicture").val());
    $("#test1").attr("src",$("#bigPicture").val());
     });
});
```

I have very weird behavior:

1. as alert I got `C:\fakepath\\[file name]` although I'm on Ubuntu machine + Google Chrome.
2. my file is not loaded rendered in img tag.
3. on FireFox I got only [filename] alert without path, and the image is not rendered as well.

Am I doing something wrong?
Is it some kind of security restriction on these browsers?

Comment: I believe this is something the browsers do to help keep you secure from any nefarious scripts that may have been loaded with the page.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

http://dev.w3.org/html5/spec/Overview.html#file-upload-state

> For historical reasons, the value IDL
>   attribute prefixes the filename with
>   the string "C:\fakepath\". Some legacy
>   user agents actually included the full
>   path (which was a security
>   vulnerability).

**filename**

> On getting, it must return the string
>   "C:\fakepath\" followed by the
>   filename of the first file in the list
>   of selected files, if any, or the
>   empty string if the list is empty. On
>   setting, if the new value is the empty
>   string, it must empty the list of
>   selected files; otherwise, it must
>   throw an INVALID_STATE_ERR exception.

Answer (score 1):

I think that you can use a file based URI such as file:///c:/test/test.jpeg.

Or if the file is local, you could make it a relative path to where the html is served.