# loading a sprite in javascript

Tags: javascript, html, loading, sprite

I'm trying to load in image in Javascript that's on my computer, so that I can make a sprite for a game. I don't have this html on the web yet, and the image is saved locally on my computer. Is this possible to do as the book I'm learning from loads the image from a folder, but I'm unable to load the image. Heres some of my code. Thanks,

```
$(document).ready(function(){

    var params ={
        images: 'C:\EclipseWorkspaces\WebTest\images\Luigi.png',
        imagesWidth: 256,
        width: 64,
        height: 64,
        $drawTarget: $('#draw-target')
    };
    var sprite1 = DHTMLSprite(params),
        sprite2 = DHTMLSprite(params);
        sprite2.changeImage(5);

        sprite1.draw(64,64);
        sprite2.draw(352, 192);
        }); 

</script>
</head>
<body>
    <div id="draw-target">
    </div>
</body>
```

Comment: Why u know search? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6233584/jquery-load-img-from-local-drive

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cant access to HD with Javascript. It would be security violation if you could so.
You can load the image in three ways.

1 You can use an image from the web

2 Use a server side program to load the image, and then pass it to your client side javascript.

3 You can do that with relatives path (../images/myImg.png)
Take a look at this article in Wikipedia:

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JavaScript#Security

Comment: Not entirely correct. If a relative path is used (say the HTML file is in directory X and the image in subdirectory x\images, then the image can be accessed using the path `/images/image.png`.

Comment: So in order to test if my code works, I need to upload the html and images onto the internet, and then I can specify the image location?

Answer (score 1):

Make the image path relative to where you store your html file. For instance put your index.html in `c:\temp` and create a folder `c:\temp\img` and put all your images in there. Then you can reference the images as `img/imagename.jpg`

Comment: This is actually what I've been doing but I'm still unable to see my images :(

Comment: If you are using chrome you might want to start it up with the "--allow-file-access-from-files" parameter. It could be that because you're using JavaScript access to your local disk is not allowed by default. Here's a list of all the chrome parameters and what they mean: http://peter.sh/experiments/chromium-command-line-switches/